# ORMLite with MYSQL - how to detect if object is shallow or deep loaded?

Tags: mysql, database, ormlite

does ORMLite has some API call to to inspect the java objected created by ORMLite and decide if it was a shallow load (ID only) or full (all fields populated?).

I know about the `refresh()` method and having a custom wrapper about DOA loader, but Im hoping there is an easier way??

Answer (score 0):

> does ORMLite has some API call to to inspect the java objected created by ORMLite and decide if it was a shallow load (ID only) or full (all fields populated?).

Unfortunately no it doesn't.  ORMLite is not returning some proxy object that it can investigate under the covers.

If you have a field that is always set can you test it yourself in your own code?  Or maybe store a `boolean` field as true all of the time or something?

Sorry to not be more helpful.